# PHP MySQL using isset($_GET)

Tags: php, mysql, database, get, isset

**Hello, I have my php script using this code:**

```
$start = (isset($_GET['start']) ? (int)$_GET['start'] : 0);

$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM menuitem LIMIT $start, 4");
```

**This pulls in the data from my database fine. Now I want to load the next 4 items from my database when a user clicks the "Next items" link, so I put this in my code:**

```
echo "<table width=\"1024\" align=\"center\" >";
echo "<tr height=\"50\"></tr>";

$next = $start + 4;
echo '<a href="?start="'.$next.'">Next items</a>';

echo "</table>";
```

Clicking the "Next items" link loads the url firstpage.php?start= but it doesn't load the next four items. Anyone see what i'm doing wrong?

Comment: There is a `"` too many in your HTML output.

Comment: Thank you! My eyes literally kept ignoring those quotes until you guys pointed it out. Thanks. Upvote for you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're using the wrong combination of quotes when outputting the link:

```
echo '<a href="?start=' . $next . '">Next items</a>';
// unneeded double quote before your $next variable
```

Comment: AH! Dang it. That was it! You're the best! Thank you! I'll accept this in a few minutes when allowed.